# "Look" of page changes a bit after uploading it to IIS - looks good on computer same IE8

Tags: html, css, iis

No it's not a path issue...or else the site won't have a design.
The website looks fine if I open it with IE8 in my computer.
But after I upload it to IIS 6.0 two things change on positioning.
I see a rendering problem. But if I open it with IE 8.0 on my machine it looks good, but opening it when uploaded to IIS , it changes a bit.
Same exact files. Same browser, same computer. The only different thing is that it has been uploaded to IIS.
IT has no programming in aspx whatsoever just .html  .css and .js

Answer (score 0):

Is a doctype added or changed?
Is the character encoding the same?
Could this be an issue of [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html)?

Comment: No doctyped added or changed. UTF-8. I discard these options.

Comment: @J Smith: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/ie8-mode.png -- this is a nice chart of IE8 going into different modes.

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing the source between the two and look for differences. Or use an element inspector built into chrome or an extension in another. Are the elements div or span tags? Can you give us details on what it is that moves?

Comment: Yeah, I usually save the source of both files, remove any references to the url with a global replace so the files should be the same and then put them through a diff tool. If you have TortoiseSVN on a Windows box, you can just surround the two files, right-click and diff them. Otherwise http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff

Answer (score 0):

Possible there's some file which isn't coming through from IIS. Try using something like Fiddler to check exactly what files (html, js, css, whatever) are being downloaded and used to render the page.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is mostly on the main menu, which is a CSS Drop Down Menu (this one right here: http://www.lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu/dropdown.nvidia.com.html ) the Nvidia menu with support for flash. I'm using this one.  It looks fantastic in my computer and all of the browsers.  But when I upload it to IIS, it is a bid bigger in 'height' , just a bit... but the rollovers notice the difference.  I uploaded the same files, to Apaceh and it works nicely in Apache.  But I need to get5 this on IIS for yesterday ! ...IT has no database, just a login form ...that would be the only db thing there, and that's not the issue.
Is is possible for an IIS to screw something tht way ? Doesnt make sense to me.'

BTW Liori, this is the message that appears when I click in your link.

Huoltokatkos lauantaina 27.3.2010

Lauantaina 27.3. fiMUG ry:n vapaaehtoiset ylläpitäjät tekevät koko päivän töitä, kun osa yhdistyksen palvelimista siirretään uuteen laitetilaan. Sähköpostilaatikoiden kokoa kasvatetaan fidiskillä 500 megatavusta kahteen gigatavuun.

Samalla fiMUG ry. osallistuu WWF:n Earth Hour -kampanjaan, jossa sammutetaan valot klo 20.30–21.30. fiMUG ry. haastaa jäsenet ja yhteistyökumppanit sammuttamaan myös tietokoneensa.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, overrides the setting in ie

META Tag in HEAD element of your web page (or better in master page)

```
<meta http-equiv=“X-UA-Compatible” content=“IE=8” />
```

link here to info 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx